# Google Map not working when wider than 800 pixels

Tags: google-maps

My Google map is not working when I set its width to a value higher than 800 pixels. If I set its width to any value less than 800px or less, it works.

check this:
01. 900px width, map is not working,
02. 800px, width map is working,
01. link:  www.designclime.com/demo/googleMapProblem/contact-1.html
  02. link:  www.designclime.com/demo/googleMapProblem/contact-2.html

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[redacted]"></script>

<script>
   var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(23.810332,90.412518);
    function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom:12,    
    zoomControl:false,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter
      });
    marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: That's an interesting behaviour. Google Maps doesn't behave that way, until there is some script on page which is messing up with the initialization of Maps. Try to resize the browser or open developer console to play around and see if that loads the map properly. If yes, then  as a workaround replace last line in script tag with google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', setTimeout(initialize, 1000)); where 1000 is time in millsec. Adjust that with as per your choice.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS problem (your map doesn't have a size if its width is greater than 800px).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue. ([fiddle containing your code with a map 850px wide](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a5a4dL76/))

Comment: check this: 1.   900px width, map is not working: http://designclime.com/demo/googleMapProblem/contact-1.html                                    2.  800px, width map is working: http://designclime.com/demo/googleMapProblem/contact-2.html

Comment: It looks like a CSS issue for me too. If you check the network activity you will see that Maps API downloads tiles imagery successfully, but it is not visible for some reason. http://imgur.com/hMPLb8A

Comment: yes... problem is solved

Comment: Hi @DelowarHosain I'm having the exact same issue.  Google maps does not render above 800px on Chrome or Firefox.  Works fine on Safari at any width.  What exactly did you do to solve this issue?